# agregar comillas despues del al obtener un printenv

Tags: regex, bash, awk

necesito algun tipo de expresion que al momento de obtener variables de entorno con printenv, me arroje lo siguiente:

`LC_TERMINAL_VERSION="3.4.16"`

usando el comando:

`printenv | grep LC_TERMINAL_VERSION|awk -v OFS="\"" '{print "",$1,$2""}'`

obtengo: `"LC_TERMINAL_VERSION=3.4.16"`

pero necesito que las comillas solo queden después del signo igual.

Alguna idea?

Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) de este modo:

```bash
printenv | grep PATH| sed -e 's/=/=\"/' -e 's/$/\"/'
```

donde en el primer parámetro `-e` del sed buscamos el primer igual `=` y le agregamos las comillas, y en el segundo nos vamos hasta el fin de linea y allí las agregamos también.

Si le quitas el `grep PATH` lo hará en todas las variables de entorno.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! si me funciono :)

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción es con `awk`:

```
$ printenv | awk -F "=" -v key="LANG" '$1 == key {printf "%s=\"%s\"\n", $1, $2}
```

Donde hacemos que el separador sea el igual "=", y la clave que busque sea "LANG" (puedes hacer que busque cualquier otra).

Luego le ordenamos a `awk` que si el primer valor corresponde al valor de `key`, entonces imprima tanto el primer valor como el segundo con el formato:

```
<primero>="<segundo>"\n
```